# Thickbox - Multiple line captions

Tags: jquery, thickbox, image-gallery

I'm trying to make an overlay with thickbox... it only allows one line captions...

Anyone have any alternative jquery plugins they use?

I'm trying to make something like:

http://hammer.ucla.edu/exhibitions/detail/exhibition_id/166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've enjoyed [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox).  Instead of an image, link up the whole div or remote html and put your caption and image inside.

If you do end up using facebox, know that there is an issue with IE8, but can be resolved by telling ie8 to treat the page like ie7 would like so: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`